# WCF service hanging in SendResponse

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, azure

I have a WCF REST service, hosted in IIS. Clients (primarily browsers) have been complaining about occasional hangs. I finally experienced this myself, and was able to grab some debugging info from the server. I grabbed the following screenshot from the IIS management console.

[image: Hanging Requests]

Obviously these requests have all been around for far too long.

While these requests were hanging the server was able to handle other requests just fine. I recycled the app pools a few times, with no apparent effect. During this time any requests from my browser would just hang and then be timed out by the browser. Other browsers on my same machine were able to connect to the same service with no problems. I also fired up Fiddler, and then was able to make requests from my "hung" browser through Fiddler. When I shut down Fiddler the browser became "hung" again. When I finally closed the browser entirely, the connections went away.

One potentially important point: you can't tell in the screenshot but the requests are all hanging on calls that send binary streams (photos & videos) to the client. Under the covers I'm opening a Stream from Azure Blob Storage (using OpenRead()) and then returning that same Stream from my functions. So I'm reading over the network on one side, and pumping the data out to the network on the other side.

So what's going on here? How can I prevent the connections from hanging, or at least make them time out at some reasonable point?

**UPDATE**: It appears that the browsers may be the problem. If I have an HTML5 `<video>` element on the page, and the video is big enough, the browser seems to open a connection to download the file and hold it open forever. I'm only about 75% sure about that, but I'll add an update here if/when I find out for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was entirely in the browsers. I have some pages with multiple `<video>` tags in them. It turns out that in some cases the browser will open a connection for each video and hold it open until the video is played through.

There are at least a couple different browser-side workarounds:

1. On the `<video>` tag add a `preload="none"` attribute.
2. Don't show the videos by default. Instead show an image, and then dynamically render the `<video>` tag when the user clicks on it.

Also, I apologize to the people who responded to this. I just didn't give you enough information to find the correct answer, so you never really had a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Next time this happens, run a separate instance of the same browser and fire up some other browser too(Firefox, Chrome, IE etc). You need to determine whether the problem is related to a particular browser.

I think you've discovered a bug in the browser. The fact that interposition of Fiddler temporarily resolves it suggests that it has to do with state management of connections via a particular protocol stack. If this is so then you will find that the problem is local to an instance of a particular browser.

There won't be anything you can do about it other than report it to the browser vendor.

If you can show that the bug is manifest only between IE and Azure then it is possible the bug is triggered by some quirk of Azure, in which case because it's a single vendor problem your chance of getting a resolution improves from "snowball in hell" to "don't hold your breath".

Comment: I actually did do that. The initial freeze was in Chrome, but Firefox and IE9 on the same machine were just fine. I've had other users report the bug in those browsers as well, which leads me to believe it's not a browser-specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fidler is a proxy and it injects itself in the process instead of your existing proxy. This leads me to believe that you (and others) have issues with automatic proxy settings or some other proxy setting related issues.

Comment: We don't have automatic proxies. Even if we did, it seems like the other browsers would've been affected as well. Also, I've had reports of this happening to users who were on entirely separate networks.

Comment: My answer is based on the fact that recycling app pools your connections do not get terminated immediately. If there is some middle man between service and client (like load balancer) that controls data flow could be the reason.

Comment: OK, I see where you're going. There is a load balancer in front of the servers. But the browser can't send any more requests to that server, which I think implies that the connections are held open all the way from the server to the browser.